# slow e-mail delivery, soft spf notification

Tags: spf

we have a server that saves and forwards e-mails to my own google mail (=peter@nowhow.be).

These mails are delayed, and when looking at the mail source, I noticed this spf softfail:

> (google.com: domain of transitioning bounce-md_9656357.5757fa2a.v1-bc546ca56d9342cdabd5403911d98a8c@mandrillapp.com does not designate 176.31.117.132 as permitted sender

Where and what should I adapt to resolve this issue? my nowhow.be Google spf record ?

```
Delivered-To: peter@nowhow.be
Received: by 10.55.51.2 with SMTP id z2csp2583562qkz;
        Wed, 8 Jun 2016 03:58:29 -0700 (PDT)
X-Received: by 10.25.216.27 with SMTP id p27mr3546145lfg.226.1465383509020;
        Wed, 08 Jun 2016 03:58:29 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <bounce-md_9656357.5757fa2a.v1-bc546ca56d9342cdabd5403911d98a8c@mandrillapp.com>
Received: from tesla.mdware.org (ns395193.ip-176-31-117.eu. [176.31.117.132])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id i129si345869lfe.139.2016.06.08.03.58.28
        for <peter@nowhow.be>
        (version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
        Wed, 08 Jun 2016 03:58:28 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: softfail (google.com: domain of transitioning bounce-md_9656357.5757fa2a.v1-bc546ca56d9342cdabd5403911d98a8c@mandrillapp.com does not designate 176.31.117.132 as permitted sender) client-ip=176.31.117.132;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@mail4.mcsignup.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@mandrillapp.com;
       spf=softfail (google.com: domain of transitioning bounce-md_9656357.5757fa2a.v1-bc546ca56d9342cdabd5403911d98a8c@mandrillapp.com does not designate 176.31.117.132 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=bounce-md_9656357.5757fa2a.v1-bc546ca56d9342cdabd5403911d98a8c@mandrillapp.com;
       dmarc=fail (p=NONE dis=NONE) header.from=gmail.com
Received: from mail4.mcsignup.com ([205.201.139.1]:9236)
    by tesla.mdware.org with esmtps (TLSv1.2:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:256)
    (Exim 4.87)
    (envelope-from <bounce-md_9656357.5757fa2a.v1-bc546ca56d9342cdabd5403911d98a8c@mandrillapp.com>)
    id 1bAbBs-0002qh-Uf
    for info@textthebutler.be; Wed, 08 Jun 2016 12:58:29 +0200

DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha1; c=relaxed/relaxed; s=mandrill; d=mail4.mcsignup.com;
 h=From:Sender:Subject:Reply-To:To:Message-Id:Date:MIME-Version:Content-Type; i=arborix.be@mail4.mcsignup.com;
 bh=RpCGYcbHIz9etudf4OnSA7s4RXI=;
 b=ocaeBUiTAGgwG3c4JY0qiaLWqp11eWprLlnWBByzfOD/Be8Vw1oPhaFt8xPLwVZGD5X4Ump5uMxU
   JqIESSAZcFXHCo1g62TmYYEMrsVaAB//Cr4prk8AbTKvVBV0nuM/usIfHTkTfiJf2axYmFHaDiEA
   M2clobgH3D9/1uUObb4=
Received: from pmta08.mandrill.prod.suw01.rsglab.com (127.0.0.1) by mail4.mcsignup.com id havt561jvmgh for <info@textthebutler.be>; Wed, 8 Jun 2016 10:57:46 +0000 (envelope-from <bounce-md_9656357.5757fa2a.v1-bc546ca56d9342cdabd5403911d98a8c@mandrillapp.com>)

DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=mandrillapp.com; 
 i=@mandrillapp.com; q=dns/txt; s=mandrill; t=1465383466; h=From : 
 Sender : Subject : Reply-To : To : Message-Id : Date : MIME-Version : 
 Content-Type : From : Subject : Date : X-Mandrill-User : 
 List-Unsubscribe; bh=9lmqNeHKT5f0OjBZtSPkLBZamFahWnA7PXNhVyFLTM8=; 
 b=ENzXp+Rf6nQcxFOgENeKBRLIG+j9FHYTukigbgGVPpZ/G9tN0OU64EgyaVLXmUGirf1sHO
 GqaRTkhZDgJ0NrzissIUxKgcBrxhk11/cw8KwfCTv1tag/Bcxyt4D9tzujBZqC//4NzFNdJ1
 wMbJBrw6iJzC7qUc37T10rhhs+Mr0=
From: =?utf-8?Q?Filip?= <arborix.be@gmail.com>
Sender: =?utf-8?Q?Filip?= <arborix.be@mail4.mcsignup.com>
Subject: Groen Koop: Please Confirm Subscription
X-Accounttype: pd
X-Auto-Response-Suppress: OOF, AutoReply
Auto-Submitted: auto-generated
Reply-To: =?utf-8?Q?Filip?= <arborix.be@gmail.com>
To: "=?utf-8?Q?info=40textthebutler.be?=" <info@textthebutler.be>
X-Report-Abuse: Please forward a copy of this message, including all headers, to abuse@mandrill.com
X-Report-Abuse: You can also report abuse here: http://mandrillapp.com/contact/abuse?id=9656357.bc546ca56d9342cdabd5403911d98a8c
X-Mandrill-User: md_9656357
Message-Id: <9656357.20160608105746.5757fa2a129838.75435610@mail4.mcsignup.com>

Date: Wed, 08 Jun 2016 10:57:46 +0000
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="_av-xvXrQw4ulMR5L-IXPCBDfw"
X-AntiAbuse: This header was added to track abuse, please include it with any abuse report
X-AntiAbuse: Primary Hostname - tesla.mdware.org
X-AntiAbuse: Original Domain - textthebutler.be
X-AntiAbuse: Originator/Caller UID/GID - [47 12] / [47 12]
X-AntiAbuse: Sender Address Domain - mandrillapp.com
X-Get-Message-Sender-Via: tesla.mdware.org: redirect/forwarder owner info@textthebutler.be -> peter@nowhow.be
X-Authenticated-Sender: tesla.mdware.org: info@textthebutler.be
```

Comment: Please improve the formatting of your question. For example you should use the `code sample` tool in the toolbar: `{ }` for logs. See the [help section on formatting](http://serverfault.com/help/formatting) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The mail seems to be sent by mandrillapp.com for info@textthebutler.be. And it seems that the mail server for textthebutler.be, forwards the mail to peter@nowhow.be without changing the envelope sender.

And since the mail server for textthebutler.be (tesla.mdware.org) isn't listed in the SPF record for mandrillapp.com, you get the softfail, since Google receive the mail from tesla.mdware.org, with an envelope sender *@mandrillapp.com

So I would think the problem is in the forwarding mail-server (tesla.mdware.org). This server would need to implement some kind of rewriting scheme (e.g. SRS) for the mail not to fail the SPF check.